# Auto controlling number of running similar Oozie jobs

Tags: hadoop, cron, oozie, oozie-coordinator

i have set the Oozie workflow frequency every 1 minute. Is there a config setting or way to stop spawning similar Oozie workflow if previous one hasn't completed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the coordinator action execution policy. Use the coordinator controls to specify the concurrency you want.

```
<coordinator-app name="[NAME]" frequency="[FREQUENCY]"
                    start="[DATETIME]" end="[DATETIME]" timezone="[TIMEZONE]"
                    xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
      <controls>
        <timeout>[TIME_PERIOD]</timeout>
        <concurrency>[CONCURRENCY]</concurrency>
        <execution>[EXECUTION_STRATEGY]</execution>
      </controls>
.....
```

More information: [Oozie Coordinator Specification](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html)